# Mysql table queries very slow

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm busy looking at building a matchmaking (dating-) site. The tables and queries are set up in a way i'm not happy with. It's still under construction so i'm happy to change anything in order to get it to work properly. It was very speedy until i decided to fill the database with loads of records to see how it performs.

Beware, this is a rather long post with lots (i hope the right...) information.

I have been googling' and reading in books for days now but A) the query performs very slowly (no wonder, it's no good i think) and B) i'm not getting any further with it.

So i hope somebody can help me to tell me what i'm doing wrong, what i should be doing and how to speed the query up. It's taking as long as 10-20 seconds to generate a result set and thats not good, anybody knows..

The information:

I have a table called 'profiles' with about 500.000 records in it. (at this time, could be more in the future)

Profiles table:

[image]

example contents:

[image]

Every answer to a question gets inserted to the profiles table, as a row. There are questions who are multiple choice so every answer selected by the member will be inserted as a new row in the profiles table and there are questions which can only have one answer thus one row in the profiles table.

Also, there is the table 'status' in which i keep record of members blocking or favoriting each other:

[image]

example contents:

[image]

Once the member fills in his/her criteria, php dynamically builds the query which needs to fetch records from the profiles table:

[image: profile table]

You can imagine how big this select query will get if all 90 questions are in the sql statement above..

Explain tells me this:
[image]

Basically i want to query the profiles table, fetching members matching the given criteria. The criteria are:

- the criteria that the member who searches entered as his/hers will retrieve matching members as a result
- the current member (the one who searches) should not be in the result(s)
- members who are present in the status table with a status of 'block' should not be in the result(s)

I'm aware (now) that the 'where in' clauses are not very fast, the indexes could be wrong and the maybe my whole table lay-out needs to be different, but i hope somebody can either point me or help me in the right direction. After a day of trying and googling' i'm at my wits end.

If you need more information, just shout! Hopefully somebody can help me.

Comment: Not a database expert, but I've seen carefully placed indexes drastically improve performance.  But my intuition is that your database schema isn't ideally laid out for this query. I will try and look at this later and think about it.

Comment: Hi Nathanial, yes if you would i would be so grateful! i have a feeling that my indexes aren't very good, nor that my query isn't ok with all these 'ins'. And maybe the whole table lay-out is wrong. Just don't know what to do differently. I'm open to any and all feedback as i'm at a loss and so much want to go forward. Thanks again!

Comment: Well...i bumped my head and saw the light, i think. I normalized the database and through foreign keys and unique constraints it is now working as i wanted it and blazingly fast at that!

when i enter a profile for a new user, the user gets created and coupled with an existing profile or one that has been made especially for this user if it is a profile that wasn't entered before.

perfecto!

Comment: Apologies for my delay, I got caught up in other projects.  I'm glad you figured it out!